# How would I "refresh" a discord embed on discord.js? More info down vv

Tags: javascript, discord.js, embed, discord-buttons

I am coding a bot on discord.js, and I was wondering how I could make this so that the embed would refresh after the button is pressed? What should happen is the embed's enemyamt value would be changed, however it does not refresh. It actually does change the value though, as shown through `button.channel.send(enemyamt);` I was thinking it can be done in one (or more) of these ways:

1. Have it be refreshed. Apparently it is through message.edit() ? I do not know.
2. Have the message be deleted and then resent, updated.

I have the code below, only snippets of it however since I do not want it to take up too much space. And yes, I know it doesn't look the best lol. Thank you in advance :)

````
    if (button.id === 'charge') {
        enemyamt = 75;
        button.channel.send(enemyamt);
    }
    if (button.id === 'rally') {
        //button.channel.send('Vive le Roy');
        //enemyamt = 75;
    }
})

client.on('message', message => {
    if (message.content === '!battle') {
        let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setColor('#318CE7')
            .setTitle('Battle')
            .addField('<:rebel:852380749242957824> Rebel Forces', enemyamt + ' hussars\nMorale: ' + enemymor + '%', true)
            .addField('<:HKPL:852380579248341022> HKPL Forces', homeamt + ' hussars\nMorale: ' + homemor + '%', true)
            .setImage('https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/798525635215360003/852027255336599552/unknown.jpeg')
            .setFooter('Niech żyje król')
        
        let btn1 = new disbut.MessageButton()
            .setStyle('red')
            .setLabel('⚔️ Charge')
            .setID('charge')
            //.setDisabled()

        let btn2 = new disbut.MessageButton()
            .setStyle('red')
            .setLabel(' Rally')
            .setID('rally')
            //.setDisabled()

        message.channel.send({ buttons: [btn1, btn2], embed: embed})
    }
})```
````

Answer (score 0):

The .send method also is a Promise and the callback is the message handle, so you can just take this handle and use the .edit method on it

```
message.channel.send("My Initial Message").then(msg => {
    msg.edit("My edited Message");
});
```

Comment: 1. Thank you very much!
2. I added that code in, and for "My edited Message" would I just put ```{buttons: [btn1, btn2], embed: embed}``` again?
3. Again, thank you :)

Comment: You put the exact same things as you would put for channel.send()

Comment: Hmm.. interesting. When I do that, it works, but only if I type the command again? Is there a way to replace the original embed or like refresh it? (And thank you very much)

Comment: To copy a message's embed, use this: `var embed = button.message.embeds[0]`. This way, you can send the embed the same way, however, I think you will need to copy paste the buttons code.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, but how would I do that? Like would I define it at the top or in the client.on? And what is the buttons code? Thank you and sorry for the questions and late reply